# How to calculate target concurrent users for a JMeter stress test?

Tags: jmeter, stress-testing

I want to stress a website and I need to calculate the concurrent users (thread group). I read that there is a rough estimation for this:

> No concurrent users = Length of user session / 60 mins * No peak hour
>   visitors

Google Analytics for this site sets 32K users like historical user limit. So what I did is:

**Concurrent Users = 4 / 60 * 32000 = 2133**

I have other data such as:

```
 - Think Time: 45 sec. 
 - Response time: 5 sec.
 - Ramp Up: 5000 users/hour.
```

Should I take Think Time, Response Time and Ramp Up to improve the estimation? How can I do this?

Comment: What is seg in think time and response time?

Comment: Sorry, seg is sec (seconds). I just fix it.

Comment: Should you consider think time? yes user session time is usually the time for which the user session is alive so yes you should consider think time.

Comment: But Think Time is included in Lengh of user session. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes that is what meant when i said you should consider think time it is not included in response time. So user session time = response time + think time

Comment: Ah! Ok. This session time = response time + think time is per request. If we have a transaction with 3 request, the Leng of user session = session time * number of requests. Right?